# Is it possible to use nextval of a sequence as default value of a field in a table in infomrix database?

Tags: triggers, sequence, informix

I have a table named T1 with a field `id(int8)` and a sequence named `seq_id`.

Can I use `seq_id.nextval` as a default value for `id` in informix database?

Or another way, can I use a trigger to update `id` before insert with `seq_id.nextval`?

Comment: Succinctly, the answer is “No”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Informix you cannot use a sequence `NEXTVAL` as a default value for a column.

One option is to turn the column into a `BIGSERIAL`.

Other option is with an insert trigger. I did not find a way to directly assign the sequence `NEXTVAL` in the trigger definition, but it can be done by using a stored procedure.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id 
    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 
    MINVALUE 0 
    NOCYCLE CACHE 10 
    ORDER; 

CREATE TABLE t1
(
      id BIGINT NOT NULL
    , val1 CHAR(4)
);
```

I found 2 ways to use the procedure. A generic procedure that returns the sequence `NEXTVAL` and a trigger procedure, that assigns the sequence `NEXTVAL` to the id.

Using a generic procedure:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION spl_get_seq_id()
RETURNING BIGINT AS seq_id_next;
    DEFINE seq_id_next BIGINT;
    LET seq_id_next = seq_id.NEXTVAL;
    RETURN seq_id_next;
END FUNCTION;

CREATE TRIGGER t1_ti
    INSERT ON t1 REFERENCING NEW AS new_ins
    FOR EACH ROW
    (
        EXECUTE FUNCTION spl_get_seq_id() INTO id
    );
```

Inserting a few values into the table and checking the result:

```sql
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( 1000, 'AAAA' );
INSERT INTO t1( val1 ) VALUES ( 'AAAB' );
INSERT INTO t1( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( NULL::BIGINT, 'AAAD' );

SELECT * FROM t1;

id val1

 1 AAAA
 2 AAAB
 3
 4 AAAD
```

Using a trigger procedure:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER t1_ti;

CREATE PROCEDURE t1_ti_spl_get_seq_id()
REFERENCING NEW AS new_values FOR t1;
    LET new_values.id = seq_id.NEXTVAL;
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE TRIGGER t1_ti
    INSERT ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW
    (
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_ti_spl_get_seq_id() WITH TRIGGER REFERENCES
    );
```

Inserting a few values into the table and checking the result:

```sql
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( 1000, 'AAAE' );
INSERT INTO t1( val1 ) VALUES ( 'AAAF' );
INSERT INTO t1( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( NULL::BIGINT, 'AAAH' );

SELECT * FROM t1;

id val1

 1 AAAA
 2 AAAB
 3
 4 AAAD
 5 AAAE
 6 AAAF
 7
 8 AAAH
```

I used `BIGINT` for the `id` column, but it should work for `INT8` (as to why did I use it, seems there is some benefits: [Counters and codes: BIGINT, INT8, INTEGER, and SMALLINT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ids_ddi_193.htm)).

**EDIT 1:**

In response to your comment, you can try a condition on the trigger, based on the session user. This will only work if the cdc software is using a dedicated user. In this example, `cdc_agent` is the user that the cdc software uses in Informix.

```sql
DATABASE db1;

GRANT CONNECT TO cdc_agent;
GRANT CONNECT TO myuser;

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id 
    INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 2 
    MINVALUE 0 
    NOCYCLE CACHE 10 
    ORDER; 

GRANT SELECT ON seq_id TO cdc_agent;
GRANT SELECT ON seq_id TO myuser;

CREATE TABLE t1
(
      id BIGINT NOT NULL
    , val1 CHAR(4)
);

GRANT ALL ON t1 TO cdc_agent;
GRANT ALL ON t1 TO myuser;

CREATE PROCEDURE t1_ti_spl_get_seq_id()
REFERENCING NEW AS new_values FOR t1;
    LET new_values.id = seq_id.NEXTVAL;
END PROCEDURE;

GRANT EXECUTE ON t1_ti_spl_get_seq_id TO cdc_agent;
GRANT EXECUTE ON t1_ti_spl_get_seq_id TO myuser;  

CREATE TRIGGER t1_ti
    INSERT ON t1 REFERENCING NEW AS new_ins
    FOR EACH ROW WHEN ( USER <> "cdc_agent" )
    (
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_ti_spl_get_seq_id() WITH TRIGGER REFERENCES
    );
```

Inserting a few values into the table and checking the result:

```sql
-- with user "cdc_agent"
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( 11, 'AAAA' );
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( 13, 'AAAC' );
-- with user "myuser"
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( 1, 'AAAB' );
INSERT INTO t1( id, val1 ) VALUES ( 3, 'AAAD' );

SELECT * FROM t1;   

  id val1

  11 AAAA
  13 AAAC
   2 AAAB
   4 AAAD
```

Comment: is it possible too keep the source value without disabling target trigger? im using this table as a target table in cdc replication and trigger changes the source value as inserted into target.

Comment: You need to explain better what you want. Maybe with some examples of what is expected to happen. If you want to preserve the values coming from CDC, then what is the use for the sequence?

Comment: because i have inserts in destination too. the sequence in source generates odd numbers for id and the sequence in target generates even values for id to prevent duplicate data.

Comment: If you cdc software does not support suppressing triggers at the target table, one way of doing it would be to put a condition on the trigger. If you can guarantee that the cdc user is only used for cdc, you can place a condition on the trigger based on session user. If it is the cdc user, do nothing, else, replace id by sequence nextval.

Comment: I have update the answer with  a possible solution for a conditional trigger.